# RuntimeError: Failed to start camera: no allocate memory

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

ı cant use my arducam imx519 16mp camera. when ı run my code ı m getting the error:

RuntimeError: Failed to start camera: no allocate memory

ı have seen some solution on different sites such as :

add cma-256 on config.txt or cmdline.txt but both didnt work.
it my meminfo:
[meminfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gn0N.png)
[config.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFRcl.png)